# Query on how to manage large lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, large-lists

I'm facing a dilemma on how to best use SharePoint 2013. I have a requirement of creating a solution that will be used around 600 users. Each user will create at least 1 task so each day there will be around 600 items which will be stored in List 1. Based on List 1 data(using lookup option), users will then create items in List 2 and assign them to individual teams. The data in the List 2 may be more than 600 per day.

The solution does work fine but I have to do the data backup almost every 1 month just to make sure the threshold limit is not crossed

I would like your help in suggesting me any solution that can be used in managing such complex solution. One such solution I'm thinking of is splitting the List 2 into several lists, just to maintain its sanity.  One more option I found was to use Access file and store the info in it. However, I should develop a front end UI for the users to add info to it. Did anyone use this approach?

Any other solutions recommended?